# How do we delete only certain events in an index in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I wanted to know if there is any command that can be used to delete a specific event after indexing. I'm using windows.

Comment: Do you know the event ID? Can you look it up in Kibana by expanding the event?

Comment: Yes i have an event id. Say AVEf9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a specific document in your Elasticsearch index. You just need to know the index name in which it resides, its mapping type, and its id (e.g. `AVEf9`). Then you can use the [delete API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html) in order to achieve it.

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/index_name/type_name/AVEf9
```

Comment: So to delete multiple events at once?

Comment: @kaks: for multiple events see my answer below

Comment: Your question asked for "specific event", but if you need for multiple events, then what @mikeb said ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess marvel-sense is helpful when you want to run large queries. I used the following to delete data which existed before 10 minutes from now.

```
 DELETE /movie1_indexer/movie/_query
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp":{
        "lt":"now-10m" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

lt-less than.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL or WGET (you might want to install CYGWIN or something similar):

The following example shows how to delete `tweets` from the `twitter` index that have the user value of "kimchy".  Read about the elasticsearch query structure to understand the JSON in the 2nd example

Search API -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-search.html
Delete via Query -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-delete-by-query.html

```
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query?q=user:kimchy'

$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

You could also install REST Easy or some similar browser plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resteasy/nojelkgnnpdmhpankkiikipkmhgafoch?hl=en-US

Comment: So in the curl command you mentioned, twitter is the index name and tweets is the type? What is _query? And does it delete only a particular field:value in an event? I'm new to ELK.

Comment: See my edit (and the documentation linked in the answer)

Comment: I tried 
$curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/trial_indexer/_query?q=No. of views:250" 
where No. of views is the field name. But i got the following response:
 curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: Instead of starting with DELETE, why don't you use a GET to make sure your query returns the proper records, then do a DELETE?    You might have to urlencode the field name, but testing with GET is going to be the best way.

Comment: Note that delete by query was deprecated in 1.5.3 and was scheduled to be removed in 2.0.

Comment: @mikeb : when i used GET i got the same result: curl: (52) Empty reply from server.

Comment: I used sense plugin to enter the following query:

DELETE /trial_indexer/_query
{
    "query":
    {
        "match":
        {
            "No. of views":"250"
        }
    }
}

It worked fine. Thanks :)